# Why does strtotime gives different values

Tags: php, datetime

See the below code

```
$compDate = date('d/m/y',strtotime('-2 weeks'));
echo strtotime($compDate)."-->".strtotime('-2 weeks');
```

The echo outputs `1398882600-->1388938336`.

Why does the time stamp differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is the wrong format - as stated by [Sharanya Dutta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21219256/1557526). The second one is you are losing precision when formatting to `m/d/y` instead of `m/d/y, H:i:s` eg.

```
$compDate = date('m/d/y',strtotime('-2 weeks'));

print date("d.m.Y @ H:i:s", strtotime($compDate)); //05.01.2014 @ 00:00:00
print date("d.m.Y @ H:i:s", strtotime('-2 weeks')); //05.01.2014 @ 17:23:42
```

When you add hours, minutes and seconds to `$compDate`, it will work as expected

```
$compDate = date('m/d/y, H:i:s',strtotime('-2 weeks'));
var_dump( strtotime($compDate) === strtotime('-2 weeks')); // TRUE
```

---

If you don't need the time but only the date, you can set the time in the `strtotime()` as well.

```
$compDate = date('m/d/y',strtotime('-2 weeks'));
var_dump( strtotime($compDate) === strtotime('-2 weeks, 0:0:0')); // TRUE
```

Comment: Um, yeah. when you call `strtotime` *later* in the code, it will return a different value. Time has passed.

Comment: Even in that case the timestamp wouldn't differ much. i can press refresh a minimum of 3 times with in a second. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is from the PHP manual:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

So change `d/m/y` to either `d-m-y` or `m/d/y` and [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) will work perfectly.

**Update:** Yes, [kingkero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1557526/kingkero) is right. You have to change `d/m/y` to either `d-m-y H:i:s` or `m/d/y H:i:s`. The point is that you can’t ignore the hour, minute and second.

Comment: I tested 'd-m-y', and it doesn't match

Comment: `m/d/y :1388860200-->1388939310` `d-m-y:1105641000-->1388939260` i am not getting it right

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` assumes `x/x/x` notation is American and `x-x-x` notation as European. Since you are passing in `d/m/Y` as the formatting for `$compDate` and then passing that date string through `strtotime()` as second time, it is interpreting the date string as `m/d/Y` the second time. You can confirm by changing your code like this:

```
$compDate = strtotime('-2 weeks');
echo $compDate . "-->" . strtotime('-2 weeks');
```

or this way:

```
$compDate = date('d-m-y',strtotime('-2 weeks'));
echo strtotime($compDate) . "-->" . strtotime('-2 weeks');
```

or this way:

```
$compDate = date('m/d/y',strtotime('-2 weeks'));
echo strtotime($compDate) . "-->" . strtotime('-2 weeks');
```

A better solution would be to use the `DateTime` class, which allows you to define the date format of a given string using `createFromFormat` so that the parser knows which number is which:

```
$compDate = date('d/m/y',strtotime('-2 weeks'));
$compDateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $compDate);
echo $compDateObject->format('U') . "-->" . strtotime('-2 weeks');
```

That last example is a bit convoluted because generally with a relative string like `-2 weeks` you wouldn't also need to worry about the formatting, but I'm guessing the issue you're really having is that the date format used throughout your code is in `d/m/y`, so the above gives an idea of how to swap between that format and and epoch timestamp. If you want to use `DateTime` to get a relative date (like `-2 weeks`), you could revamp the above as:

```
$compDate = new DateTime('-2 weeks');
echo $compDate->format('U') . "-->" . strtotime('-2 weeks');
echo $compDate->format('d/m/Y');
```

If you want the timestamp to be for the date but don't want to use time, you can add `today` to the relative format, like so:

```
$compDate = new DateTime('2 weeks ago today');
echo $compDate->format('U') . "-->" . strtotime('-2 weeks 00:00');
echo $compDate->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: $compDate = date('d-m-y',strtotime('-2 weeks'));
echo strtotime($compDate) . "-->" . strtotime('-2 weeks'); doesn't give o/p as said